# No Keyboard or trackpad when Dual Boot Linux + MacOs Mojave

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, keyboard, mouse

I am currently trying to dual boot Linux with Mojave on my early 2015 Macbook. I am encountering an issue when booting into Linux to install where my keyboard and mouse do not work at all once moving past the GNU Grub screen. I am new to Linux so I am not very advanced, but I have been trying many of the offered solutions with no luck. I have tried the most recent and older versions of several distros. If anyone has experienced this problem or has any suggestions that would be great.

Tl;dr Trying to dual boot Linux on Early 2015 Macbook. I have controls on the GNU Grub screen, but once I try to boot into Linux I have no output from keyboard or mouse.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to mention the name of the distro & its version in case the solution depends on that knowledge.

Comment: I’ve tried Fedora (Workstation 29), Ubuntu, Manjaro(KDE Version) and Mint (19.1 Cinnamon). The most recent versions of Manjaro, Fedora, and Mint as of two days ago, and Ubuntu 18.04.1, 12.04.5, and 14.04.5.

Comment: Additionally, USB keyboards and mouses will not work either.